# Unable to pass data to method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I am trying to use AJAX with ASP.NET for the first time - by trying to pass the following data to a WebMethod in my corresponding aspx page:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myurl.aspx/SaveScreen",
    data: "{'data': " + JSON.stringify(arrayRows.data) + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    }
});
```

Here is my WebMethod in the aspx page. I have tried passing a simple data object which just contained one key and value, which worked successfully. When attempting to pass this object, I get an error stating that there is an internal server error with code 500.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You absolutely should not concatenate strings when an object definition can be used instead. Concats are far less readable.

Comment: what was you parameter datatype in Web method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
`data: {"data": JSON.stringify(arrayRows.data)}`

Comment: This is the sensible solution, rather than concatenating strings, and I note from other edits that you posted this solution first.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the data string in quotations:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SpecifyPositioning.aspx/SaveScreen",
    data: "{'data': '" + JSON.stringify(arrayRows.data) + "'}", //Added ' around JSON.stringify to pass string instead of object
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    }
});
```

---

This however would be a cleaner solution:

```
data: {"data": JSON.stringify(arrayRows.data)},
```

Comment: This has solved the issue, thanks. Is it possible to pass the data without stringify? If so, how?

Comment: you cannot pass an `Array` to a `WebMethod` directly as far as I know, so the only replacement for `JSON.stringify` I know of would be `arrayRows.data.join()`

Comment: Your later addition is the sensible way to do it. Creating an object definition as a string, when that is not needed, is adding pointless layers of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
data: "{data: '" + JSON.stringify(arrayRows.data) + "'}"
```

Comment: While it "works", creating a string for an object definition is not only pointless, but leads to bad practices. The up-voted answer is the correct way to do it. I see however someone is sympathetic to you and has up-voted... defeating the whole purpose of the voting :)

Comment: So I should use **data: {"dataName" : stringValue}** instead?

Comment: Yes. Keep it simple (and especially *easier to read*). The `data` parameter can be an object with any named properties you want. The names will depend on what the receiver wants to see. In the asker example the `data` has a property called `data` which presumes the receiver wants a parameter called `data` (I would avoid generic names like data where possible as that is also confusing).